# How do I generate a 2D Gaussian with a mean 50 and standard deviation of 5

Tags: python

I would like to create a 2D Gaussian array with a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 5. How is this possible? The size of the array is 50x50

Comment: Peptone = np.random.multivariate_normal([25, 25], [[25, 0],[0, 25]], 50)

Comment: Thanks, it's easier to get help on SO if you post what you've tried and the problem you ran into

Comment: I tried the above code but I end up getting a 50X2 array rather than a 50X50 array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.random.randn`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html):

```
import numpy
import math

50 + 5 * numpy.random.randn(50, 50)
```

Comment: How would that give me a 50x50 array?

Comment: @GowthamJawaharram the mean 50 is broadcasted into the 50x50 numpy array.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @Scott thanks. But this distribution does this give me a gaussian? Sorry, but my math is not so great.

Comment: Yes it does. the ``n`` in ran**n** stands for Normal (i.e., Gaussian).

Comment: @GowthamJawaharram Yes, is returns a sample from a standard normal, N(0, 1), also known as a Gaussian distribution with mean=0 and std=1 http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

Comment: @Scott Is it possible to make other distributions say for example a distribution that obeys sinusoidal wave with all numbers positive?

Comment: @GowthamJawaharram In general we should limit comments on stack overflow.  Additional questions can be googled, or searched within stack exchange or posted as a new question.  But to your question, yes, sort of.  You can make a noisy sine wave. `x=numpy.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 100)` then `n=0.1*numpy.random.randn(len(x))` and finally `y=2+numpy.sin(x) + n`.